# Is it possible to traverse SVG DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, svg

I am making an ajax get call to a web page and return the html, I append the html to a jQuery defined div. I have tried a multitude of different ways to try to traverse the SVG DOM, ideally in jQuery this is what I would like to do:

```
$(div).find('g.pt1').each(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

I have tried KeithWood's SVGjQuery plugin but I can't figure it out, I have tried selecting the svg element by class and setting it as my context when selecting the g tag, I looked into Snap.SVG but it kept throwing an error that Snap was not defined. Any help traversing SVG DOM?

EDIT: AJAX does not return the SVG tag at all

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    success: function (data) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        $(div).find('[id^="chart"] g text').each(function () {
            g = this.innerHTML;
            alert();
        })
        $('#a-page').append(div)
        alert('passed the find')
    }
})
```

I appended it to the page and went through to find where it is an I get this:

```
<div id="chart582u5" style="width:93%;"></div>
```

When it should be this, like how it is on the normal page:

```
<div id="chart582u5" style="width:93%;">
    <style></style>
    <svg class="pzchart" height="260" width="388" viewport="0 0 388 260" viewBox="0 0 388 260" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g>
            <text>what I want</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it in jQuery without any plugins:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="1">
            <text x="250" y="150" font-size="55">Hello</text>
            <text x="300" y="200" font-size="55">World</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<script>
    var a = []
    $('#container g text').each(function(){
        a.push(this.innerHTML);
    });

    alert(a.join(','));
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/untit1ed/hz1uy4c7/2/)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, and when I specify the container of the svg element it returns nothing. I am looking for 'g' tags, even more specifically the 'text' tags inside the g tag.

Comment: Is the container required or a container with an ID? I can't get it to alert, it's the same syntax from what I can tell

Comment: post your svg and your selector. I think your selector might be the issue.

Comment: I edited my post to show what I am doing and what I am getting, I guess it isn't traversing the SVG DOM but not receiving the SVG DOM in the first place

Comment: It works just fine, here's the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/untit1ed/dbk9c3sa/ Check the console for errors and your ajax page for unclosed/broken tags.

Comment: In my edit I said that I am not even receiving the svg tags, in the #chart582u5 div, it returns with empty content

Comment: In your edit xhr is not defined. You should replace `xhr.responseText` with `data`. Here's a working ajax demo - http://jsfiddle.net/untit1ed/dbk9c3sa/1/. Also check the network tab of your browser to make sure you receive what you expect.

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/dqafndh9/ is what I am receiving in my app. That chart div is empty, everything from that page returns except the inside of that div

Comment: In that case the problem is on your server. If the browser doesn't receive SVG then it can't really parse it, can it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = $('<div/>')
            .attr('id', 'chart582u5')
            .css('width', '93%'),

    yourText = 'hello world';

var svgDOM = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'))
            .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
            .attr('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
            .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid')
            .attr('width', 388)
            .attr('height', 260)
            .attr('viewBox', '0 0 388 260')
            .html('<g><text x="50%" y="50%">' + yourText + '</text></g>');

div.append(svgDOM);
$('body').append(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GenerateUniqueStrID() {
  var CurDate = new Date();
  return '<UID>' + CurDate.getTime() + '</UID>';
}

$.ajax({
        url: href+'?' + GenerateUniqueStrID(),
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(data).find("selector").each(function(){
                console.log($(this));
                /*******************************************
                your XMLFile must look like this template for exemple:
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <yourData>
                  <selector></selector>
                  <selector2>
                    <selector></selector>
                    ....
                  </selector2>
                </yourData>
                *******************************************
                create your elements on the fly
                *******************************************/ 
            //})
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error! "+ textStatus);
        },
        complete: function(textStatus) {
            console.log('completed');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try D3js library. I've been using it for all sorts of svg things. works great.